# Why does fabs always return a integer 1 when used in another file than main

Tags: c, linux

In my code in C which is consists of multiple sources files and headers, I have to use `fabs` in one of my functions. But every time I use `fabs` it just return an integer equal to 1.

I found one post here that talk about that (no post on other websites) but the answer not corresponding for me. The answer was to link math library with `-lm` but I have already done that, and to include math but I also did that...

So I don't understand why it returns 1 and it's really stuck me for my internship because it was a important function for the entire code.

Here's my function and the include in the header `polynome.h` and `maths_jauge.h`

```
#include "maths_jauge.h"

double newtonMethode(double *poly, double valeur, int degre, double x) {
    double scalaire[1];
    scalaire[0] = -valeur;

    double *polyInter = malloc((degre + 1) * sizeof(double));
    additionPoly(degre, poly, 0, scalaire, polyInter);
    free(polyInter);

    int degreDerive = degre - 1;
    double *derive = malloc((degreDerive) * sizeof(double));
    derivePoly(degre, poly, derive);

    while (fabs(evalPoly(x, degre, poly) - valeur) > 0.001) {
        x -= evalPoly(x, degre, polyInter) / evalPoly(x, degreDerive, derive);
    }

    free(derive);
    return x;
}
```

Include in `maths_jauge.h`:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include "polynome.h"
```

Include in `polynome.h`:

```
 #include <math.h>
```

And here's my makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g
LDFLAGS = -lm

all : main.o polynome.o maths_jauge.o
    $(CC) $^ -o main $(LDFLAGS)

main.o : main.c polynome.h
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

polynome.o : polynome.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

maths_jauge.o : maths_jauge.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY : clean mrproper

clean :
    rm -f *.o

mrproper : clean
    rm -f main
```

Comment: What are the values of `evalPoly(x, degre, poly)` and `valeur` in a typical `fabs(evalPoly(x, degre, poly) - valeur)` case?

Comment: Interesting how fabs can return an integer. Probably it returns value > 0.001. Assign the result of fabs to the variable and print it. you will get your answer

Comment: Should not there be a + 1 in `malloc((degreDerive) * sizeof(double));` as in `malloc((degreDerive + 1) * sizeof(double));`?

Comment: @chux she just shud output the result. It is the another example of complete lack of OP effort to solve the problem

Comment: MCVE would help. I don't believe you.

Comment: `evalPoly(x, degre, polyInter) / evalPoly(x, degreDerive, derive);` fail as `polyInter` is free'd.

Comment: You have `-Wall` turned on, but you didn't say whether you are getting any warnings.

Comment: First : I found out that I had a problem because just launch the code (that compile with no warning, that's weird because like you saiid @chux I've modified my code so quickly and forgot to move the free of PolyIInter) make an infinite loop.

Comment: So I've used gdb to know what happend, the infinite loop start at this function, I found two things, one, this code don't exactly make what I want but this it's my personal problem, two, when i'm trying to display `fabs` of something I always have 1 at result... in the exemple I've tring to use, valeur take the value 4.6703... and `evalPoly(x, degre, poly)` it's near to 0 so I display `evalPoly(x, degre, poly)  - valeur' that give me -4.6703... but fabs of this give me 1....

Comment: @PeterJ You should stop judge people about that they forgot to put all the outputs here. I past one entire hour with an intensive use of gdb and man to exactly find where's the problem in my code and trying to understand why fabs doesn't work here as it work in another case but even type in gdb with breakpoint at newtonMethode `fabs(-4.6)` return 1

Comment: @DaphnéPORTERIES Did you try [increasing the allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382625/why-does-fabs-always-return-a-integer-1-when-used-in-another-file-than-main?noredirect=1#comment77726666_45382625) by 1?

Comment: @DaphnéPORTERIES `fabs(-4.6) return 1` for 1 of 3 reasons 1) earlier code is  doing something wrong (UB) 2) `fabs(-4.6) return 1` is incorrect and your detection method of determining the return value is in error.  3) `#include <math.h>` is not truly occurring before using `fabs()`.

Comment: Where and how is `evalPoly` declared? Also post the actual definition.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the code as the same way fix it, so I still don't why it was acting like that.

Thanks.

This is the rewrited code without errors that peoples highlighted :

```
double newtonMethode(double *poly, double valeur, int degre, double x) {
    double scalaire[1];
    scalaire[0] = -valeur;

    int i = 0;

    double *polyInter = malloc((degre + 1) * sizeof(double));
    additionPoly(degre, poly, 0, scalaire, polyInter);

    int degreDerive = degre - 1;
    double *derive = malloc((degreDerive + 1) * sizeof(double));
    derivePoly(degre, poly, derive);

    while (fabs(evalPoly(x, degre, poly) - valeur) > 0.000001) {
        x -= evalPoly(x, degre, polyInter) / evalPoly(x, degreDerive, derive);
    }

    free(polyInter);
    free(derive);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Post the re-written code, else this is just a comment and not an answer.

Comment: We have to give a little wiggle room here, Rep < 20 can't comment...But, to @chux point, when you get a reputation > 20 (and you will), comments are for questions or requests for further information (and even for answers to questions that shouldn't have been asked -- such as those requesting info on page 1 of any howto), and answers are for answers that resolve the question, or a significant part of the question.

Comment: Ok, I will edit my post to add the new code that work.